# Details of this definition of an initial segment of a binary structure

Tags: definition, relations, order-theory

I am going over some notes and am a little confused over a couple details. What I have:

> Let $(X,\leqslant_X)$ and $(S,\leqslant_S)$ be binary structures such that:
>
> - $S\subseteq X$
> - $\color{blue}{\leqslant_S\;\subseteq\; \leqslant_X}$
> - $\forall s\in S,\forall x\in X\;(x\,{\color{red} \leqslant}\, s\implies x\in S)$
>
> Then $(S,\leqslant_S)$ is called an initial segment of $(X,\leqslant_X)$.

The points I am a little unsure of:

- in the expression in blue, are we allowing $\leqslant_S$ to *not* be the restriction of $\leqslant_X$ to $S$ but to be a proper subset of this restriction? I don't quite understand the need for this line otherwise.
- the symbol in red, should I take this to mean $\leqslant_X$? Again, I'm confused as to why we don't write the relation as $\leqslant$ throughout, and perhaps write $\leqslant\big|_S$ for the restriction on the initial segment.
- finally, the $\leqslant$ symbol is suggestive of at least a pre-order, is the concept of an initial segment of not much interest for arbitrary binary relations? The definition above looks like it would apply to any such relation.

Comment: Apparently, $\leq_S$ could just be the identity on $S$, provided $\leq_X$ is reflexive. I think the definition would be much more useful if $\leq_S$ was the restriction of $\leq_X$ to $S$. That should be the case if $X$ were an ordered set and $S$ an initial segment; for more general settings, I just suppose it should be the same, but I don't know for sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been made
unduely complicated and myopic.
Let S be an ordered set.
A subset S is an intial segment of S
when A is a lower set:
for all s in S, a in A, (s <= a implies s in A).
Viewed as an ordered set in itself,
A has the inherited or restricted order of S.

Comment: Ok phewf, that is the feeling I was getting. And so the notion of a 'segment' only really applies if the relation is an ordered one.